# Consuming a JSON Payload with Dynamic dates as fields

Tags: apex, rest-api

I'm going to be consuming a JSON payload through a `GET` service, it's a very large payload which I'm handling fine except for the `nativeRateInfo.nightlyRates` and `convertedRateInfo.nightlyRates`

```
{
"id": 131,
"nativeRateInfo": {
    "subtotalRate": 3150,
    "nightlyRates": {
        "2017-04-05T00:00:00.000Z": 630,
        "2017-04-06T00:00:00.000Z": 630,
        "2017-04-07T00:00:00.000Z": 630,
        "2017-04-08T00:00:00.000Z": 630,
        "2017-04-09T00:00:00.000Z": 630
    }
},
"convertedRateInfo": {
    "subtotalRate": 3935.3,
    "nightlyRates": {
        "2017-04-05T00:00:00.000Z": 787.06,
        "2017-04-06T00:00:00.000Z": 787.06,
        "2017-04-07T00:00:00.000Z": 787.06,
        "2017-04-08T00:00:00.000Z": 787.06,
        "2017-04-09T00:00:00.000Z": 787.06
    }
},
"isCurrencyConversionFailed": false,
"mvgInfo": {
    "id": 90
},
"created": "2017-03-24T12:14:18.547Z",
"updated": "2017-03-24T12:14:19.480Z"
}
```

I cut the payload down a lot in order to save some space, but I my question is how do I handle `nightlyRates` when the field name won't be same every time, I don't have control over the end point.

The following is my object that I'm deserlizing into, again this is cut down to save some space.  The object that I created is working correctly and building it nicely, it's just the `nightlyRates` node I don't know how to handle

```
public class ReservationRateResponse
{
    public Integer ID;  //131

    public ReservationNativeRateInfo nativeRateInfo;
    public ReservationConvertedRateInfo convertedRateInfo;
    public boolean isCurrencyConversionFailed;
    public ResevationMVGData mvgInfo;
}

public class ReservationNativeRateInfo 
{
    public String currencyCode; //GBP
    public Double averageDailyRate; //575.83
    public Integer totalRate;   //3455
}

public class ReservationNightlyRates 
{
   /* public Double 2017-04-05T00:00:00.000Z; //787.06
    public Double 2017-04-06T00:00:00.000Z; //787.06
    public Double 2017-04-07T00:00:00.000Z; //787.06
    public Double 2017-04-08T00:00:00.000Z; //787.06
    public Double 2017-04-09T00:00:00.000Z; //787.06*/
}

public class ReservationConvertedRateInfo 
{
    public String currencyCode; //USD
    public Double averageDailyRate; //719.38
    public Double totalRate;    //4316.33
    public Double conversionRate;   //1.2493
}

public class ResevationMVGData 
{
    public Integer id;  //90
    public ReservationNativeRateInfo nativeRateInfo;
    public ReservationConvertedRateInfo convertedRateInfo;
    public boolean isCurrencyConversionFailed;
}
```

Comment: Wow, sending a date as the key for a key-value pair sounds like an abysmally bad idea. Is it feasible for you to modify this payload at the source? Failing that, can you modify that data in Apex to convert `nightlyRates` into a list of sub-objects (with date and rate keys)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talk about abusing JSON syntax. The correct solution to parsing this sort of broken JSON is to have a Map:

```
public Map<DateTime, Double> nativeRateInfo;
```

From there, you can use normal Map methods to examine the nights that were sent to you and their associated values.

Edit: Decimal apparently uses 28 bytes per value, while Double uses only 12, so you can save 16 bytes of heap per key this way. Without being able to massage the data, make sure you use a DateTime, not a Date.